# How to write any type of file (for example txt file) to a resources folder with the config.property file, but without using absolute path file in java

Tags: java, io, resources, classloader, properties-file

***How to write or read any type of file*** (for example `.txt` file) to a resources folder with the `config.property` file, but without using absolute path file.

I tried to solve this like below:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Setting.class.getClassLoader();
Setting setting = new Setting();

try (InputStream resourceAsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
   setting.load(resourceAsStream);
}

String readFileName = setting.getValue("pathSource.txt");
String writeFileName = setting.getValue("outPutPathSourceFile.txt");

String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");

File readFile = new File("./src/main/resources" + File.separator + "pathSource.txt");
File writeFile = new File("./src/main/resources" + File.separator + "outPutPathSourceFile.txt");
```

However, I don't want using `./src/main/resources` prefix.

Comment: So basically, you want to know if there's a special mapping/placeholder for the resource directory ?

Comment: Welcome to So. You mean something like `System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources"`  ?

Comment: Yes, exectly like System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources"
but without using forcibly this string "/src/main/resources"

Comment: @ВарданМатевосян is your issue solved?

Comment: If I try:
File readFile = new File("./src/main/resources" + File.separator + "pathSource.txt");

yes it work, but it's bad solution.

Comment: Resources (files on the class path, possibly inside a jar)can be read, but are not intended to be written to. You can use them as template to create an inital copy on the file system.

Comment: Joop Eggen thanks, perfect hit, sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources (files on the class path, possibly inside a jar)can be read, but are not intended to be written to. You can use them as template to create an inital copy on the file system. – Joop Eggen

Answer (score 0):

If your file is located under `resources` you able to access it like:

> File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

if you are using Spring you can use [ResourceUtils.getFile()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html):

> File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:fileName")

**UPDATE:**

If I understand correctly, you want to read file which located under your `src/main/resources` without relative path usage `/src/main/resources`.

I created small demo:

```
public class ReadResourceFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "webAutomationConfig.xml";
        ClassLoader classLoader = ReadResourceFile.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

        System.out.println("File exists: " + file.exists());

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
File exists: true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <baseUrl>https://www.gmail.com</baseUrl>
</config>
```

***Project structure:***

[image]

Comment: No, I want using file located in resources, how I can do it without this line:
"/src/main/resources"
p.c But this -> File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile()); using file in the folder where progect start

Comment: getFile() produce a NullPointerException oooo

Comment: @ВарданМатевосян you have a bug in your project. You need to post more info about your - project structure and code.